# jQuery: Check if two classes exist per div

Tags: jquery

I have two questions per `div` (page) that look like this:

```
<div id="page5" class="page" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="question">
                        <h3>9. You are trying to remember a pin number, what are you most likely?</h3>
                        <ul class="abc Clearfix">
                            <li>
                                <span>
                                    <a class="a" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                        <span class="letter">A</span>
                                        <span class="image"></span>
                                        <span class="title">Imagine the numbers in your head</span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>
                                    <a class="b" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                        <span class="letter">B</span>
                                        <span class="image"></span>
                                        <span class="title">Repeat the numbers out loud</span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>
                                    <a class="c" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                        <span class="letter">C</span>
                                        <span class="image"></span>
                                        <span class="title">Try out the pattern of the numbers on a keypad</span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="question">
                        <h3>10. How would you tell if a friend was upset?</h3>
                        <ul class="abc Clearfix">
                            <li>
                                <span>
                                    <a class="a" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                        <span class="letter">A</span>
                                        <span class="image"></span>
                                        <span class="title">Notice the expression on their face</span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>
                                    <a class="b" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                        <span class="letter">B</span>
                                        <span class="image"></span>
                                        <span class="title">Listen to what they say</span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>
                                    <a class="c" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                        <span class="letter">C</span>
                                        <span class="image"></span>
                                        <span class="title">Pick up on their body language</span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have some jQuery code that allows the user to select a link per question (they can ONLY choose one per question). Their are a total of 5 pages that the user can navigate across using a next and previous set of links. What I want to do is check that a div with the class of page has two classes of selected on its links, otherwise show an alert when the user tries to click a button.

The code to do the selects on the options.

```
$(".abc li a").click(function ()
{
    var selected = $(this).hasClass('selected');
    $(this).closest('ul.abc').find('li a').removeClass('selected');
    if (!selected)
        $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

The navigation buttons used to jump between pages:

```
<div class="page-navigation Clearfix">
                                <a id="quiz-prev" class="Prev" href="javascript:void(false);" style="display:none;">
                                    <span>Prev</span>
                                </a>
                                <a id="quiz-next" class="Next" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                    <span>Next</span>
                                </a>
                                <a id="quiz-finish" class="Finish" href="javascript:void(false);" style="display:none;">
                                    <span>Finish</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
```

and the code for the next button:

```
   $("#quiz-next").click(function () {
        $(".page:visible").hide().next().show();
    });
```

So if a user was on `page1` and had only clicked one option ie. only one link had a class of selected then when they clicked the next link it would show an alert saying 'Please fill out all questions'. **Note: I have already added code to hide and show the buttons based on what page they are looking at so don't need to do that**

Also when the user reaches the last page, a finish button appears so it needs to check the user has selected 10 options, so need to either count the classes or something similar. Cheers again for all who can help.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

**EDIT: Here is my attempt to show an alert if two options have not been clicked. But it shows the alert all the time**

```
$('#quiz-next').click(function ()
{
    var allOK = true;
    $('div.page > div.question').each(function () {
        allOK = allOK && $('a.selected', this).length == 1;
        return allOK;
    });

    if (allOK == false)
    {
        alert("Please fill in all questions");
    }
    else {
        $(".page:visible").hide().next().show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically what you need to do is this:

In a `<div class="page">`, you have several `<div class="question">`. On a triggered event, you want to make sure that *each* question div has *exactly one* `<a class="selected">` before proceeding.

The following code should be able to do that:

```
var allOK = true;
$('div.page > div.question').each(function() {
    allOK = allOK && $('a.selected', this).length == 1;
    return allOK; // if false, we don't need to check the rest
});
```

After running this code, `allOK` tells you if you're good to go or not.
It [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/MYT3u/10/), at least =)  (You'll have to put the select classes there manually...)

Note: this will check for *all* `<div class="page">` that are currently rendered (which seems to be what you want for the last page). To just check a single `div` at a time, you'll have to change the `div.page` selector to something uniquely identifying that specific div - with your sample code, you could for example use `#page5` instead.

Comment: There are two question divs per page. And each question can only have two options (selected states on their links) This part is handled already. But I want to make it so that the user MUST have selected two options before the next link will work and all 10 options before the finish button will work. Instead I want to show an alert saying please complete all questions.

Comment: @Cameron: That's exactly what my code helps you do. Have you played around with the jsfiddle?

Comment: @Thomas Yes I have looked at the JSFiddle, but I'm not sure how to properly use it as I just get an alert saying false...?

Comment: @Cameron: I've updated the jsfiddle to demonstrate how to use my code. Please take a look at it.

Comment: @Cameron: Sorry, the link to JSFiddle only worked to get the original entry - my updates did not show up. I've now linked to the correct revision, which should give you an idea on how to use it.

Comment: @Thomas see OP I have added some code for my attempt but it ALWAYS shows the alert even if I have checked two options? Cheers

Comment: @Cameron: Please look at the updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/MYT3u/10/ if you haven't already. If you're updating that fiddle, you need to send me a link, because I don't see your update.

Comment: @Thomas I have added my code to the Original Post up top. I have looked at the updated fiddle but please take a look at mine as I think I have understood and used an if and else statement to check if true or false per page but the alert always appears? Cheers

Comment: @Cameron: You're not using the code as I showed in my fiddle. The code to check for selected links goes *inside* the click handler for the next button, and the number you check the length against should be the number of allowed choices *per question*.

Comment: @Thomas it is now inside the click handler and I've changed the number but I still get the alert all the time...? Cheers pal for the help.

Comment: @Cameron: Did you read the note at the end of my answer? You'll have to update the `div.page` selector to something else (perhaps `.page:visible`, as in your original code?) if you have more than one `<div class="page">` on your page when clicking "next".